# Change of basis matrix notation confusion

Tags: matrices, coordinate-systems

I've got strange notation of change of basis matrix in my book and I'd like to have it explained a little bit. It says, if:

$M _{\mathcal A}^{\mathcal B}(id) \cdot \vec{v} _{\mathcal B} =  \vec{v}_{\mathcal A}$

then $M _{A}^{B}(id)$ is change of basis matrix from the basis $A$ to the basis $B$. It completely breaks my intuition, because in the result, we have a vector represented in the basis $A$!

On same page in this book, they say:
$\phi(\vec{v})=\vec{w} \iff M _{\mathcal B}^{\mathcal A}(\phi) \cdot \vec{v} _{\mathcal A} =  \vec{w}_{\mathcal B} $
It brings even more confusion.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's the change of basis matrix from the basis $B$ to the basis $A$. You get the $A$-coordinates of a vector $\vec{v}$ by multiplying the $B$-coordinates of $\vec{v}$ with $M_A^B(\operatorname{id})$.

Comment: The book clearly says that it's opposite to what I would think or what you say. I added notation of transformation matrix in my first post. Could you relate to that? Maybe they are just wrong...

Comment: The notation is consistent with what I said (well, it should be $$M_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{A}}(\phi)\cdot \vec{v}_{\mathcal{A}} = \vec{w}_{\mathcal{B}}$$ and not $\vec{v}_{\mathcal{B}}$). It's probably only a typo in the book, they confused $A$ and $B$ in one place.